# How do you pause code in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, wait, sleep, pause

I want to be able to change the background color of a button when pressed, then change it back half a second later. I have tried many things, but for some reason, most don't work.

For example, Thread.sleep(500); gives me an error, SystemClock.sleep(500); pauses the UI, and for some reason I cannot make a handler using Handler mHandler = new Hander(); No solution that I have found has worked so far.

Comment: You ***don't*** *pause* the UI thread. You **send a message that you'll want something to be executed 500 ms later**. Use a Handler with `Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());` and use `handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {...}, 500);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *never* pause or sleep the main / UI thread!

What you will want to do is add code that runs in the background to change your button color. There are many ways to do this:

`Handler`

`AsyncTask`

POTs (Plain Old Threads)

If you do it by trying to pause the UI, you are also pausing *everything else on the screen* which is not what you want.

Comment: I realized why I couldn't use a handler, I forgot to import the class. Also, maybe I wasn't clear; I wasn't saying that I wanted to pause the UI thread, I said that it's not what I want.

Comment: It looked like you were trying to pause the UI, but I think I realize that you were trying to "pause the button" - which is "pause the UI" because that is where it resides. I'm glad the answer helped!